# How to use SQL CONCAT to concatenate columns and include "&" between them if there is another following

Tags: mysql

I would like to concatenate columns and place an "&" between them if there is another following, e.g.:

- Camp
- Camp & Den
- Camp & Den & Hike
- Camp & Den & Hike & Off site
- Camp & Hike
- Hike

The SQL I have is:

```
SELECT cs_id, acc_id, cs_site, CONCAT(cs_suburb, ' ', cs_state, ' ', cs_postcode) AS city,  
       cs_first_contact_name, CONCAT(IF(cs_camp_site = 1, 'Camp', ''), ' ',  
       IF(cs_offsite_visit = 1, 'Off site visit', ''), ' ', IF(cs_scout_den = 1, 'Den', ''), ' ',  
       IF(cs_hike = 1, 'Hike', '')) AS type, cs_max_campers  
FROM at_camp_site   
ORDER BY cs_site;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), which will add a separator *only* between any non-`NULL` values, so to avoid extra separators, make the default for each value `NULL` instead of `''`:

```
SELECT cs_id, 
       acc_id,
       cs_site,
       CONCAT(cs_suburb, ' ', cs_state, ' ', cs_postcode) AS city,  
       cs_first_contact_name, 
       CONCAT_WS(' & ',
                 IF(cs_camp_site = 1, 'Camp', NULL),
                 IF(cs_offsite_visit = 1, 'Off site visit', NULL),
                 IF(cs_scout_den = 1, 'Den', NULL),
                 IF(cs_hike = 1, 'Hike', NULL)) AS type, 
       cs_max_campers  
FROM at_camp_site   
ORDER BY cs_site;
```